# why it fetch the correct row and the others else message

Tags: reactjs

RectJs `   {this.state.certificats.map((Certificat, key) => {
if (Certificat.id.toString() == '2' ) {
return (




ID
Etablissement universitaire
Diplome
Mention
Nom et Prenom
CIN
Date du naissance
Date d'obtention
Admin

```
         </tr>
       </thead>

                 <tbody id="certificattList">

                 <tr key={key}>
                  <th scope="row">{Certificat.id.toString()}</th>
                  <td>{Certificat.etablissment}</td>
                  <td>{Certificat.titrespe}</td>
                  <td>{Certificat.mention}</td>
                  <td>{Certificat.nom}</td>
                  <td>{window.web3.utils.fromWei(Certificat.cin.toString())}</td>
                  <td>{Certificat.naissance}</td>
                  <td>{Certificat.datecert}</td>
                  <td>{Certificat.owner}</td>

                </tr>
                 </tbody>

     </table>


     </div>
       )
 }  else {
   return (<div><h3>it's not exist</h3></div>}
```

})}
`why it fetch the correct row and the others else message for exapmple if you have 5 rows it show one correct with if condition and the other 4 rows withe esles condition that mean the Else condition workd even when i've the right condtion , thanks for help